# Elastic Beanstalk: IAM policy for deploying a multicontainer Docker environment from a private repository

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, elastic-beanstalk

How do I enable my environment under Elastic Beanstalk to talk to S3 so that it can get the authentication info and then pull my Docker image from a private repository in a multicontainer environment?

I found the name of the IAM role in my environment's instance config ("aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"), went to IAM, opened the "AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier" policy in order to extend it for S3 access to the ARN for my bucket, but these policies are "AWS Managed" and read-only. I tried merely attaching an existing S3 policy (e.g. AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess, defined by AWS) to my instance-profile role, but the deployment failed and the logs still complain about not being able to access the private repository:

```
2018-01-10T02:56:10Z + local 'CONTAINER_STOPPED_REASONS=nomad-service-identity: CannotPullContainerError: API error (404): repository dsoprea/nomad not found: does not exist or no pull access'
2018-01-10T02:56:10Z + '[' -n 'Essential container in task exited' ']'
2018-01-10T02:56:10Z + error 'ECS task stopped due to: Essential container in task exited. (nomad-service-identity: CannotPullContainerError: API error (404): repository dsoprea/nomad not found: does not exist or no pull access)'
2018-01-10T02:56:10Z + echo 'ECS task stopped due to: Essential container in task exited. (nomad-service-identity: CannotPullContainerError: API error (404): repository dsoprea/nomad not found: does not exist or no pull access)'
2018-01-10T02:56:10Z ECS task stopped due to: Essential container in task exited. (nomad-service-identity: CannotPullContainerError: API error (404): repository dsoprea/nomad not found: does not exist or no pull access)
2018-01-10T02:56:10Z + eventHelper.py --msg 'ECS task stopped due to: Essential container in task exited. (nomad-service-identity: CannotPullContainerError: API error (404): repository dsoprea/nomad not found: does not exist or no pull access)' --severity ERROR
2018-01-10T02:56:10Z + set -e
```

No mention of trying to access the authentication file, but I don't know whether to expect it to log this.

Does the config look correct?

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "volumes": [
  ],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "nomad-service-identity",
      "image": "dsoprea/nomad:identity-1",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "entryPoint": ["/nomad/nomad_identity_service"],
      "links": [
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
      ],

      "authentication": {
        "bucket": "nomad-docker",
        "key": "dockerconfig.json"
      }

    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach the correct permission for reading the registry to that EB Role. If the repository would be ECR, the permission to add would be:

```
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly
```